# No module named 'gluonts.trainer'

Tags: python

```
!pip install gluonts
!pip install atspy
!pip install gluonts
from gluonts.mx.trainer import Trainer
from mxnet import gluon
from gluonts.trainer import Trainer
from atspy import AutomatedModel
```

However, it gives me an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 4 from gluonts.mx.trainer import Trainer
> 5 from mxnet import gluon
> ----> 6 from gluonts.trainer import Trainer
> 7 from atspy import AutomatedModel
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gluonts.trainer'

I have no ideas how to solve this. If anyone has any ideas

Answer (score 3):

In the source code, I couldn't find gluonts.trainer either. Are you sure that you need line 6?

In my case, `from gluonts.mx.trainer import Trainer` was sufficient. (though I only needed to use gluonts once).